# How can I reduce noise on vocal track using Audacity

Tags: audacity, noise-reduction

I extracted vocal-only from a song using AI online service and this is the result.
[Speechless Vocal Only](https://soundcloud.com/user-525495820-428210789/speechless-vocals)
As you can see, there is still noise in this track especially on the lyrics "*Whenever they try*".
I'm new in sound editing and I can't identify what kind of noise it is.
I want to know what kind of noise it is and how can I remove or reduce from sound track.
I use Audacity for Windows.

Comment: That is pretty broad spread digital noise across frequencies - I'd suggest asking the online service to provide better output for you.

Comment: @RoryAlsop , is there any way to reduce this kind of noise ?

Comment: Realistically, no. Even Izotope would struggle with that - it's not a consistent background noise, but a digital glitch - which is why I suggested getting the original redone